# how to make Astar pathfinding can used by multi enemy?

Tags: actionscript-3, a-star

i have learn A star pathfinding  from "AdvancED_ActionScript_Animation" e-book:

- List item
- i make node class, Node.as .
- i make grid class, Grid.as  .
- i make AStar class, AStar.as .
- and the main clas, Game.as .
  A-star Pathfinding is work, but just 1 player.
  how to make it work in multi player?

> spoiler
> 4.Game.as :

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Game extends Sprite
{
    private var _cellSize:int = 30;
    private var _grid:Grid;
    private var _player:Sprite;
    private var _index:int;
    private var _path:Array;


    public function Game()
    {
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        makePlayer();
        makeGrid();
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGridClick);
    }
    private function makePlayer():void
    {
        _player =new Sprite();
        _player.graphics.beginFill(0x336633);
        _player.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,5);
        _player.graphics.endFill();
        _player.x = Math.random() * 100;
        _player.y = Math.random() * 100;
        addChild(_player);
    }

    private function makeGrid():void
    {
        _grid = new Grid(10,10);
        for (var i:int =0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        _grid.setWalkable(Math.floor(Math.random()*10),
          Math.floor(Math.random()*10),false);
        }
        drawGrid();
    }
    private function drawGrid():void
    {
        graphics.clear();
        for (var i:int =0; i < _grid.numCols; i++)
        {
            for (var j:int =0; j<_grid.numRows; j++)
            {
                var node:Node = _grid.getNode(i,j);
                graphics.lineStyle(0);
                graphics.beginFill(getColor(node));
                graphics.drawRect(i *_cellSize,
                  j*_cellSize,_cellSize,
                  _cellSize);

            }
        }
    }

    private function getColor(node:Node):uint
    {
        if (! node.walkable)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (node == _grid.startNode)
        {
            return 0xcccccc;
        }
        if (node == _grid.endNode)
        {
            return 0xcccccc;
        }
        return 0xffffff;
    }
    private function onGridClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var xpos:int =Math.floor(mouseX/_cellSize);
        var ypos:int =Math.floor(mouseY/_cellSize);
        _grid.setEndNode(xpos,ypos);

        xpos = Math.floor(_player.x / _cellSize);
        ypos = Math.floor(_player.y / _cellSize);
        _grid.setStartNode(xpos,ypos);
        drawGrid();
        findPath();

    }
    private function findPath():void
    {        
        var astar:AStar = new AStar();
        if (astar.findPath(_grid))
        {
            _path = astar.path;
            _index = 0;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }
    }
    private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        var targetX:Number = _path[_index].x * _cellSize 
        + _cellSize / 2;
        var targetY:Number = _path[_index].y * _cellSize 
        + _cellSize / 2;
        var dx:Number = targetX - _player.x;
        var dy:Number = targetY - _player.y;
        var dx2:Number = targetX - _box.x;
        var dy2:Number = targetY - _box.y;
        var dist2:Number =Math.sqrt(dx2*dx2+dy2+dy2);
        var dist:Number =Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy+dy);
        if (dist<1)
        {
            _index++;
            if (_index >= _path.length)
            {

             removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _player.x += dx * .5;
            _player.y += dy * .5;

        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is far too long for anyone to read. Please narrow your question down to the specific parts of the code that you need help with.

Comment: oh sorry,,
can you help me to edit the post?..
i think the specific code in the Game.as

Comment: I think making your question intelligible and compelling is your job. Answering it is our job.

Comment: i have edit it,, 
can u understand?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to go the extra mile and code this for you. (Anyone else can feel free to do that)

What you need to do is create a function that accepts a start node and end node, and returns the path. Something like this :

```
public function getPath(starNode:Point, endNode:Point):Array
{
    // get your path by utilizing the astar instance
    // return that path array

    // note that I have used Points to store the x,y location
    // you'll need to apply those values to the grid before your astar call
    // using the setStarNode and setEndNode methods of the grid instance


}
```

Then you can modify the code that is used in your enterFrame, to utilize an array containing path data for any player/enemy you want.

For example you might have a function you call for each entity such as :

```
public function followPath(entity:MovieClip, pathData:Array, pathIndex:int):void
{
    // your modified code from onEnterFrame
        // replace _player variable with entity
        // replace _path variable with pathData
        // replace _index with pathIndex 
}
```

If you understand OOP well enough, you might want to create a class for your player/enemy entities that has properties for pathData and pathIndex. If you do that, than you can just call an update method that will update their movement each frame using the pathData and pathIndex properties of that instance.

This is a basic approach you could use to accomplish your goal.

Comment: difficult,,
i understand the point,
but i dont how to code it. i just beginer in OOP

Comment: If you don't understand, I would encourage you to take a step back and learn about OOP. There are many books and resources for AS3 that can teach you. Without that knowledge, this is likely not a task you should be working on.

Comment: You can email me via the email on my profile and I can help you out some, but this is really not the place for something like that.

Comment: really..
god bless you